# How to get some words to replace ans stop on a word doc

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get replace some strings

When I run test1 program. It puts UserName and UserId in a text file if not there already. The code needs to  add Sharing under UserId. The code will run each time a user opens up a test1 program.

```
        string usrname = Environment.UserName;
        string MyFileName = @"C:MyPath\textfile";
        if (File.Exists(MyFileName))
        {
            StringBuilder NewFile = new StringBuilder();
            string ln;
            using (StreamReader Rdr = new StreamReader(MyFileName))
            {
                while ((ln = Rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (ln.StartsWith("UserId"))
                    {
                        ln = "Sharing";
                    }
                    NewFile.AppendLine(ln);
                }
                Rdr.Close();
            }
            File.WriteAllText(MyFileName, NewFile.ToString());
        }
```

Name
UserID
Sharing

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking. Is there a problem with this code not working the way you intend? Also, it looks like your "NewFile.appendLine(ln); statement is excluding information from the first file. is this intentional?

Answer (score 0):

change the while loop to:

```
            while ((ln = Rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                NewFile.AppendLine(ln);
                if (ln.StartsWith("UserId"))
                {
                    ln = "Sharing";
                    NewFile.AppendLine(ln);
                }
            }
```